# How can I efficiently resize a matrix in julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

What is the efficient way to resize a matrix along the first dimension, i.e. add rows?

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible for standard `Matrix` type. You can only resize `Vector` by e.g. doing `append!` or `push!`.

You can vertically concatenate two matrices, but this allocates a new matrix:

```
julia> x = [1 2; 3 4]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4

julia> y = [5 6; 7 8]
2×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 5  6
 7  8

julia> [x; y]
4×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 3  4
 5  6
 7  8
```

The reason why adding a new row a matrix in-place is not supported is that it cannot be done efficiently because of the memory layout of a matrix (essentially the cost of such operation would be similar to vertical concatenation).

You would need another data structure to be able to do such resizing in place. For example `DataFrame` from DataFrames.jl supports this (but note that quite likely vertical concatenation I have described above is best for your use case):

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a=[1,2], b=[11,12])
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1     11
   2 │     2     12

julia> push!(df, [3, 13])
3×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1     11
   2 │     2     12
   3 │     3     13
```

The reason why it is possible for `DataFrame` efficiently is that internally it is a vector of vectors so you can `push!` data to each vector representing a column.

Comment: I thought it should be possible to do it at least allocation free.

Comment: It is technically impossible to grow some data structure without new allocations in general. You could, instead, write your custom matrix type that would be a wrapper around one or more matrices. Then it would not allocate. Here is an example of such implementation for vectors https://github.com/JuliaData/SentinelArrays.jl/blob/main/src/chainedvector.jl.

Comment: Why is it technically impossible? AFAIU matrix is simply a continuous block of memory with special indexing style. Thus, it should be possible to growat specific locations efficiently.

Comment: Assume you have your your data stored in memory locations 1 to 10, 11 to 20, and 21 to 30. Assume that your matrix takes memory range from 11 to 20. There is no space in memory to grow it neither in front not in the back. You would have to move whole matrix to other place in mamory.

Comment: The same way that `push!/insert!` handle the situation for vectors.

Comment: `push!` occasionally has to re-allocate the whole vector. The difference is that if you do `push!` and you do not have to re-allocate you do not have to move any data. This would be not the case with matrix.